# How to import JS files via plugin in Webstorm? Tired of importing manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, filesystems, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I do a lot of JavaScript development in WebStorm, the Jetbrains IDE, and I find myself requiring a lot of external .js files into my current JS file like below.

```
var page=require("../../../documents/doc.js");
```

It's easy to require these files if your project is small; but mine is large and spans across a maze of folders/directories and grows even larger as the development team adds to it.

It would be nice to have a plugin for WebStorm IDE which allows to maybe drag and drop the JS file and it automatically writes the `require` statement like so:

```
var page=require("../../../documents/doc.js");
```

Or maybe some way to right click on the .js file I'm trying to import and click require or import if that option exists in WebStorm?

Is there a plugin to achieve this? Hopefully you get what I'm looking for. Please do not suggest other IDEs, I'm mostly interested in a way to achieve this in WebStorm, the IDE by the company JetBrains.

Thanks